# View Favorites from iOS app

Tags: feature-request, ios-app

Can posts that have been favorited be viewed in a list on the iOS app similar to the desktop web version? If not, I'd like to request such a feature.

Comment: @PatrickHofman Not a duplicate. That is asking for a way to save searches; this is asking if one can view one's favorited questions.

Comment: The UI has changed slightly since then, so I'm going to leave my answer up.

Comment: What a weird bug, my close vote added auto upvote to @Pat comment, but it wasn't deleted when the question is actually closed.

Comment: I'm surprised that the post (of which my question is a duplicate) didn't show up in the list of proposed questions that the site recommends while creating a new question. Perhaps it was because of the different spelling of the word favorite/favourite?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes. Open the site you want to see your favorites on, tap 'More' and then 'Favorite Questions.'

[image]

Comment: Can  you please add a screenshot, especially since it changed over time?

Comment: @ShadowWizard Done :)